# a short error screen when i pop screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an order-page in my app where the user can remove the order. When the button below is pressed the order gets removed and the screen gets poped. But in that short time before the screen is poped an error and a red screen shows for half a second because the order that is recuired not exist anymore, but as the pop is completed the app works fine. How should i solve this? I know I could use a diffrent approach where the order isnt removed from its list but i want to make it work this way and I want to pop the screen before i remove the order from the list.

The error message:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Bad state: No element

```
ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Remove'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                        .removeOrder(order.id);
                    
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onPressed: () {
Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                        .removeOrder(order.id);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    
                  },
```

do this instead of your code. It is saying that remove order is calling after the `navigator.pop(context);`. Which means the screen is popped out but the function is calling for the screen.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried this now but it still doesnt work and I think it is beacuse I have another provider in the beggining of the class where listen is true (which it has to), and that provider causes the error when the order disapears, which ofcourse was impossible for you to know since i didnt include it. But I think this gets me closer, maybe i somehow could "turn of" the first provider when the remove-button is pressed...

Comment: Add a bool variable that checks if the data is loaded then you can get back to where you want your provider state or functionality to be. #learningTogether

Comment: Great that worked, thanks!!!